# Is there a difference between these codes?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in coding and I've been learning python just lately.
I tried to do some recursion exercises, my codes run most of the time but there is one thing that is worrying me.

My code is always longer than the one in the solution.

Take this exercise for example

(Write a Python program to get the sum of a non-negative integer.Test Data:sumDigits(345) -> 12sumDigits(45) -> 9)

My answer is this

```
def sum_num(n,sum1=0):
  k=int(n)
  if k%10==k:
    return sum1+k
  else:
    sum1+=k%10
    k=k//10
    return(sum_num(k,sum1))
    
  print(sum_num(2384))
```

and the solution is this

```
def sumDigits(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return n % 10 + sumDigits(int(n / 10))

  print(sumDigits(345))
  print(sumDigits(45))
  print(sumDigits(345))
  print(sumDigits(45))
```

My code run perfectly but it's just longer. My question is 'is it okay to have a long code, if not how can I learn to shorten it'.

Thank you

Comment: fix the indentation

Comment: "is it OK to have long code?" Depends how long and what code. "How can I learn to shorten it?" Practice and read other people's solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, writing shorter and cleaner code is good practice because when you have long code thats hard to read its going to be harder for you and especially oher people to work with it, and troubleshooting can be really difficult. Think simple and try to write it as clean as it could possibly be. There isnt really a way to LEARN it but practice and studying and just trying to think simple should help.